# Getting anchor that contains bold tags with xPath?

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, html-parsing, domxpath

I am using xpath and I am trying to get the anchor text from a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://link.com"><b>anchor</b> text</a>
```

I tried getting the anchor text with the xPath:

```
.//a/text()
```

But I only get "text" as result, not "anchor text".

**How do I get the full text?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> .//a/text()
> ```

The reason that the text node containing "anchor" is because this text node is child of `b` -- not child of `a`. The above expression selects only text nodes that are *children* of any `a` that is a descendant of the current context node.

**Use**:

```
.//a//text()
```

This selects all text-nodes that are *descendants* of all `a` elements that are descendents of the current context node.